# mvn sonar:sonar throws exception while doing Java AST scan

Tags: sonarqube

**Please note :- My mvn clean install goes successful**
but when i do mvn sonar:sonar it throws me

```
[ERROR]  Squid Error occurs when analysing :/junk/test/src/main/java/API/com/API/HelloAPI.java
org.sonar.squid.api.AnalysisException: The source directory does not correspond to the package declaration com.API
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitor.PackageVisitor.checkPhysicalDirectory(PackageVisitor.java:93) [sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.8.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitor.PackageVisitor.createSourcePackage(PackageVisitor.java:75) [sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.8.jar:na]
```

http://sonar-dev.787459.n3.nabble.com/file/n3324837/squid-test.zip

Answer (score 3):

The message is quite clear: the package declaration is wrong. It should be API.com.API if the source directory is /junk/test/src/main/java (that is the default value in Maven). An alternative is to change the source dir to src/main/java/API.

Comment: if the package declration is wron my mvn clean compile install also failed it throws the exception while issuing mvn sonar:sonar log file can be found at [link]http://sonar-dev.787459.n3.nabble.com/file/n3325121/log-files

Comment: Any Update on this , i'm blocked on this or my Q is not clear

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your POM contains this line:

```
<sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
```

If so, changing it to this might help:

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
```

Maven doesn't care, but sonar does.

I had the same problem with sonar and a maven project generated by eclipse.

(Found the solution at http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/13899/13064/ )

Comment: I have the same error but, when I change the sourceDirectory as you propose, maven can't found any sources to compile. I'm trying to analyse a legacy app who have two source folders and the only way I found to make this work was with this configuration of pom.xml file: <sourceDirectory>.<sourceDirectory> and <includes>
            <include>foo/**/*.java</include>
          </includes>

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message after upgrading to a more recent sonar plugin (sonar-maven3-plugin:3.7.1/3.7.3/4.0 running against SonarQube Server 3.5.1) for a source file which worked with 3.6-RC3/3.6.3/3.7.0. Apparently 3.7.1 introduced the issue :-/