# sonar analysis on maven multimodule project with nonstandard directory structure

Tags: maven, build, sonarqube

I'm trying to mavenize a project. The code base is beginning to bloat and it needs to be split into multiple modules. However, we already have a somewhat proprietary deployment process in place and the directory structure cannot be compromised in favor of the Maven way.

The simplified structure is as follows:

```
  /workspace/basesrc/
                    |_ superpom.xml
                    |_ com/company/parentpkg/
                                          |_ ModuleA/
                                                    |_ pom.xml
                                                    |_SubAModuleA/
                                                                 |_ SubAModuleAClass.java
                                                                 |_ pom.xml
                                                    |_SubAModuleB/
                                                                 |_ SubAModuleBClass.java
                                                                 |_ pom.xml
                                          |_ ModuleB/
                                                    |_ ModuleBClass.java
                                                    |_ pom.xml
```

I was able to build the project using the following setup:

**Approach A**

(superpom.xml):

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

This is inherited by the submodules, in effect building only its current directory.

**However**, Sonar seems to have trouble resolving package names if this is the case as stated in this thread: [mvn sonar:sonar throws exception while doing Java AST scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370521/mvn-sonarsonar-throws-exception-while-doing-java-ast-scan).

**Approach B**: Specify the root source directory and use maven compiler inclusions, as explained here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

(superpom.xml)

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>/workspace/basesrc/</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

(SubAModuleA pom.xml)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <includes><include>com/company/parentpkg/ModuleA/SubAModuleA/**/*.java</include></includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Again, this works for the case of maven build. But Sonar seems to include the whole `/workspace/basesrc/` folder despite running `mvn sonar:sonar` from a submodule directory.

SO my question is,

If I use Approach A, is there a way to configure/override the root directory property in which Sonar Maven Plugin is searching for Java source files? Can it be different from the  ${project.build.sourceDirectory} maven property?

Using Approach B, How can Sonar be configured to analyze only what is being built by maven-compiler-plugin?

Comment: I think it's important to tell us what package the SubAModuleAClass has. Is it com.company.parentpkg.ModuleA.SubAModuleA ? If so, I dont see the reason for having any submodule hierarchy there. Just go for the superpom and do the analysis there.

Comment: Hi Peter,Yes it is com.company.parentpkg.ModuleA.SubAModuleA. However, the contents of this package is meant to be a self contained module. And besides, that's the point of implementing a multimodule project right? To be able to separate a source base into self contained reusable components?

Comment: well, in the maven each of your submodules should contain full package hierarchy, rather than just an end class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested, just to reiterate `<sonar.includes>` must be placed under `<properties>` instead of `<configuration>` under `<plugin>`. And sonar must be version 3.5 up.

Answer (score 0):

well, I think following should help you to setup your project: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

See the section:

> Producing Multiple Unique JARs from a Single Source Directory

Please understand that it's not the way things should be setup in maven, as you're breaking the convention, that makes maven so strong. On the other hand I understand that in some projects there is no option for changing the source structure to the way maven convention says it.

Comment: Hi Peter, this could be an option, but this doesn't make any difference in the sonar analysis vs the Approach B I mentioned above. It still analyzes the whole code base as a single project. What would be ideal is to be able to selectively analyze a submodule without taking in all the source codes from other modules.

Comment: are you sure, it's the same? I believe the difference to your setup is that they use: <sourceDirectory>../src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
in the submodule, did you do that? For your case: <sourceDirectory>../../../../</sourceDirectory> (if I counted the packages correctly :))

Comment: I came across this a while ago, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065400/maven-sonar-exclude-folder-from-analysis. So I added, <sonar.inclusions>[insert maven-compiler-plugin inclusion filter here]</sonar.inclusions>. However , judging from the length of the analysis it seems that Sonar is still looking at the other submodules? Or am I just mistaken in the usage?

Comment: What I meant was, it is still results in the same single source folder sonar analysis, rather than having separate modules be analyzed selectively. Did I get you right?

Comment: Got it. should be as a project property and sonar version must be 3.5 up.